# TypeError: this.setSate is not a function (bind(this) or something else? if bind(this) where does it go?)

Tags: reactjs

Its a click handler for the hamburger button that opens a side drawer.
"TypeError: this.setSate is not a function." By the looks of it, it has to do with an update that requires bind(this) but I'm not sure if it's true or something else.

I tried placing bind(this) in different places but I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
class Home extends Component {
    state = {
      sideDrawerOpen: false
    };

    drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
        this.setSate((prevState) => {
          return {sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen};
        });
    };

    render () {
      let sideDrawer;
      let backdrop;

      if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
        sideDrawer = <SideDrawer />;
        backdrop = <Backdrop />;
      }

      return (
        <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
            <NavBar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />
```

Comment: You've got a typo, this.setSate -> this.setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo you wrote setSate instead of setState, you missed the first t in state